# Ember js v1: refresh (remove / re-add) observers in 'control' view when data (model) is replaced in controller

Tags: ember.js

I have created a fiddle that accurately represents our issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/EbenRoux/PLS3y/

The problem we have is that we add an observer in a child view.  The object that the observer is bound to is replaced in the controller and the child view effectively stops working.  We need to get to the child view to set up the new observer.

When one clicks the 'new model' button the 'data' property is replaced.  So the observer added by the following is now referencing the previous model:

```
Ember.addObserver(this.get('validator').get('model'), 'someProperty', this, this.validate);
```

How would one get to the `ValidatorView` to remove and re-add the observer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a binding on the controller for the model, and observe the model on the validator view.

```
    var binding = Ember.Binding.from('data').to('validators.someValidatorName.model');
    binding.connect(controller);
```

as shown on this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JurgenFlurgen/RYG4X/